# How to find symbolic links to the current file?

Tags: php, perl

Is there a way in PHP or Perl to find all symbolic links to the current file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without traversing the filesystem looking for all symbolic links and then checking their destination, no.  But if you still want to do this, it's pretty straight-forward:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $target = 'the filename you want to find links to';
finddepth(
    sub {
        return if not -l $File::Find::name;
        print "found $File::Find::name!\n" if readlink($File::Find::name) eq $target;
    },
    '/'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid scanning the whole file system, but I appreciate the code :-)

Answer (score 4):

Not without walking the filesystem or using `find` (which itself walks the FS).  Symlinks aren't actually linked to a file in any meaningful way; they just contain a path to the real file.  Those links can be anywhere, and the OS doesn't necessarily know about them at all til they're used in a path.

Answer (score 2):

Not without searching the entire filesystem.

Symlinks (in linux at least) are basically pointers.  They point from one location to another, but the location they point to has no way of knowing what points to it without an exhaustive search.

You could do this with a full search, but it could easily take a long time depending on your system.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you could - in theory - use a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and set it to traverse from the filesystem root. You could then check if the [currently iterated filesystem item is a link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.islink.php) and if so, use [readlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readlink.php) to see where it points to:

```
$fsi = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/'),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
foreach ($fsi as $fso) {
    if ($fso->isLink()) {
        echo readlink($fso->getPathname());
    }
}
```

In practise, you will likely not be allowed to do that from the user executing the PHP script.